# Ending a looping thread using Events in Python 3.5

Tags: python, multithreading, events, python-multithreading

I am having trouble with stopping a looping thread. I use an event to stop the loop but the output is different than I expected. I wrote the following code

```
import threading 
from time import sleep

class foo(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stop_event = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        while not self.stop_event.is_set():
            print('1')
            sleep(1)
            print('2')
            sleep(1)
        print('done')

class bar(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
       threading.Thread.__init__(self)
       self.run_thread()


    def run_thread(self):
       th1 = foo()
       th1.start()
       sleep(4)
       th1.stop_event.set()

prgm = bar()
prgm.run_thread()
```

Gives me the output:

```
1
2
1
2
1
done
2
1
2
done
```

I expected the word 'done' to be printed onces when the while loop ends. But for some reason 'done' is printed twice. Am I using Events wrong or is the thread started multiple times?

Comment: I added print(''hallo') before the while (inside the thread). The output prints "hallo" twice. So for some reason the thread is started twice.

Answer (score 1):

You already do `self.run_thread()` in the constructor of `bar` (i.e. `bar.__init__`):

```
class bar(...):
    def __init__(self):
       threading.Thread.__init__(self)

       # !!!!
       self.run_thread()
```

So, when you create an instance of `bar`:

```
stuff = bar()
```

You're *executing `bar.run_thread` as well*. Your current code executes this function *twice*:

```
prgm = bar() # executed here
prgm.run_thread() # and here
```

As a result, you get some unexpected behavior.

Comment: Oops. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Missing two points:

1. Add `if __name__ == '__main__':` before `prgm = bar()`
2. Add `sleep(0.1)A` before each `run...`

Comment: How would adding "if __name__ == '__main__':" improve the code? Other than improving the overall 'design' of the code.